# Modificar consulta mysql script datatables

Tags: mysql, datatables

Estoy intentando editar el siguiente código sin éxito.

Si no se selecciona ningún filtro de fecha o se escribe  algún carácter en el imput seach se muestran todos los registro de la tabla. 
Lo que estoy intentando es que por defecto no muestre todos los registros y establecer un  filtro mediante un WHERE.

No entiendo toda la lógica del código, pero solo hay dos lugares donde se realiza la consulta a la tabla viajes.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM viajes WHERE";
```

y

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM viajes";
```

He intentado añadir el siguiente WHERE pero cuando lo introduzco  me pasa lo siguiente.

Si modifico la primera query por:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM viajes WHERE id='1'";
```

Aparece un error del script datatables y no se muestra ningún registro

"DataTables warning: table id=order_data - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1"

Si modifico la segunda query por:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM viajes WHERE id='1'";
```

Sigue mostrando todos los resultados de la tabla como si no hubiese añadido la condición WHERE.

Gracias por vuestra ayuda.

ajax.php

```
<?php
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "pruebas");//Configurar los datos de conexion
    $columns = array('idviaje', 'apodocliente','fechacar','apodopro','nombrechofer','coste','pvp');

    $query = "SELECT * FROM viajes WHERE";



    if($_POST["is_date_search"] == "yes")
    {
     $query .= 'fechacar BETWEEN "'.$_POST["start_date"].'" AND "'.$_POST["end_date"].'" AND';
    }

    if(isset($_POST["search"]["value"]))
    {
     $query .= '
      (idviaje LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 
      OR apodocliente LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%")
     ';
    }

    if(isset($_POST["order"]))
    {
     $query .= 'ORDER BY '.$columns[$_POST['order']['0']['column']].' '.$_POST['order']['0']['dir'].' 
     ';
    }
    else
    {
     $query .= 'ORDER BY idviaje DESC ';
    }

    $query1 = '';

    if($_POST["length"] != -1)
    {
     $query1 = 'LIMIT ' . $_POST['start'] . ', ' . $_POST['length'];
    }

    $number_filter_row = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($connect, $query));

    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query . $query1);

    $data = array();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
     $idviaje=$row["idviaje"];
     $chofer=$row["apodopro"]." - ".$row["nombrechofer"];

     $fechacar=date("d/m/Y", strtotime($row["fechacar"]));          
     $sub_array = array();
     $sub_array[] = $fechacar;
     $sub_array[] = $chofer;
     $sub_array[] = $row["apodocliente"];
     $sub_array[] = $row["coste"];
     $sub_array[] = $row["pvp"];

     $sub_array[] = '<a href="edit.php?idviaje='.$idviaje.'" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></a>';
     $sub_array[] = '<a href=eliminar.php?idviaje='.$idviaje.'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>';

     $data[] = $sub_array;
    }

    function get_all_data($connect)
    {
     $query = "SELECT * FROM viajes";
     $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
     return mysqli_num_rows($result);
    }

    $output = array(
     "draw"    => intval($_POST["draw"]),
     "recordsTotal"  =>  get_all_data($connect),
     "recordsFiltered" => $number_filter_row,
     "data"    => $data
    );

    echo json_encode($output);

    ?>
```

index.php

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Filtrar datos por fechas usando datatables con PHP y MySQL</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.3.7/css/csscustom.css">  
  <link href="plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/datepicker/datepicker3.css">

  <style>
   body
   {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-color:#f1f1f1;
   }
   .box
   {
    width:1270px;
    padding:20px;
    background-color:#fff;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius:5px;
    margin-top:25px;
   }
  </style>


 </head>
 <body>

  <div class="container box">



   <h1 align="center"> Filtrar datos por fechas usando datatables con PHP y MySQL</h1>
   <br />






   <div class="table-responsive"  style="overflow-x: hidden;">
    <br />
    <div class="row">
     <div class="input-daterange">
      <div class="col-md-4">
       <input type="text" name="start_date" id="start_date" class="form-control" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
       <input type="text" name="end_date" id="end_date" class="form-control" />
      </div>      
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4">
      <input type="button" name="search" id="search" value="Buscar" class="btn btn-info active" />
     </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <table id="order_data" class="table  table-striped  table-hover">
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>FECHA CARGA</th>
       <th>PROVEEDOR - CHOFER</th>
       <th>CLIENTE</th>
       <th>COSTE</th>
       <th>PVP</th>
       <th></th>
       <th></th>
     </thead>
    </table>

   </div>
  </div>
  <script src="bootstrap-3.3.7/js/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap-3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="plugins/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 </body>
</html>



<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >



$(document).ready(function(){




 $('.input-daterange').datepicker({
    "locale": {
                "separator": " - ",
        "applyLabel": "Aplicar",
        "cancelLabel": "Cancelar",
        "fromLabel": "Desde",
        "toLabel": "Hasta",
        "customRangeLabel": "Custom",
        "daysOfWeek": [
            "Do",
            "Lu",
            "Ma",
            "Mi",
            "Ju",
            "Vi",
            "Sa"
        ],
        "monthNames": [
            "Enero",
            "Febrero",
            "Marzo",
            "Abril",
            "Mayo",
            "Junio",
            "Julio",
            "Agosto",
            "Septiembre",
            "Octubre",
            "Noviembre",
            "Diciembre"
        ],
        "firstDay": 1
    },

  format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
  autoclose: true

 });

 fetch_data('no');

 function fetch_data(is_date_search, start_date='', end_date='')
 {
  var dataTable = $('#order_data').DataTable({

    "language":{
       "lengthMenu":"Mostrar _MENU_ registros por página.",
       "zeroRecords": "Lo sentimos. No se encontraron registros.",
             "info": "Mostrando página _PAGE_ de _PAGES_",
             "infoEmpty": "No hay registros aún.",
             "infoFiltered": "(filtrados de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
             "search" : "Búsqueda",
             "LoadingRecords": "Cargando ...",
             "Processing": "Procesando...",
             "SearchPlaceholder": "Comience a teclear...",
             "paginate": {
     "previous": "Anterior",
     "next": "Siguiente", 
     }
      },

   "processing" : true,
   "serverSide" : true,
   "sort": false,
   "order" : [],
   "ajax" : {
    url:"ajax.php",
    type:"POST",
    data:{
     is_date_search:is_date_search, start_date:start_date, end_date:end_date
    }
   }
  });
 }

 $('#search').click(function(){
  var start_date = $('#start_date').val();
  var end_date = $('#end_date').val();
  if(start_date != '' && end_date !='')
  {
   $('#order_data').DataTable().destroy();
   fetch_data('yes', start_date, end_date);
  }
  else
  {
   alert("Por favor seleccione la fecha");
  }
 }); 

});
</script>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que error te aparece ? podrias copiar el mensaje de error ? seguro que no tienes que poner 'Where idviaje = 1' ?

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el error?

Answer (score 0):

Tu código tiene 2 bloques:
- uno condicional, primer bloque, cuando realizas una búsqueda entre fechas.
- segundo bloque, sin condiciones, en el que te aparecerán TODOS los resultados. Relacionada con la siguiente función, que es donde se encuentra el  QUERY que te interesa modificar.

```
function get_all_data($connect)
{
 $query = "SELECT * FROM viajes";
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
 return mysqli_num_rows($result);
}
```

Por ejemplo, si quieres limitarlo a 5 resultados por orden del idviaje más recientes:

```
   function get_all_data($connect)
    {
     $query = "SELECT * FROM viajes ORDER BY idviaje DESC limit 0,5";
     $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
     return mysqli_num_rows($result);
    }
```

Prueba a modificar:

```
<?php
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "pruebas");//Configurar los datos de conexion
    $columns = array('idviaje', 'apodocliente','fechacar','apodopro','nombrechofer','coste','pvp');

    $query = "SELECT * FROM viajes WHERE idviajes=1";



    if($_POST["is_date_search"] == "yes")
    {
     $query .= 'AND fechacar BETWEEN "'.$_POST["start_date"].'" AND "'.$_POST["end_date"].'" AND';
    }

    if(isset($_POST["search"]["value"]))
    {
     $query .= 'AND 
      (idviaje LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 
      OR apodocliente LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%")
     ';
    }
```

Comment: He añadido tu código y no afecta a los resultados, cuando cargo la página aparecen todos los registros. Me equivoque al formular la pregunta si añado un simple  $query = "SELECT * FROM viajes WHERE idviajes='1'";  no aparece ningún error , pero 
 sigue mostrando todas filas de la tabla también.

Comment: El código de la función que te puse es para 'modificarla' por la que está. Podrías poner la estructura de la tabla?

Comment: He añadido el código del archivo index.php que es donde cargo la tabla. Supongo que te referías a eso

Comment: Hola, no, la estructura de la tabla de tu base de datos SQL es el código que muestra la estructura de la tabla con sus campos definidos. Se accede a través de consola o a través de un interfaz como phpmyadmin por ejemplo. Si has modificado los querys que aparecen y no se modifica nada, solo se me ocurren 2 cosas: que haya algún otro query por otro lado o un tema de caché.

Comment: He añadido imagen con la estructura de la tabla. Otra consulta no hay, esos 2 archivos son los únicos que intervienen. Sobre la cache no sabría decir.

Comment: He añadido otra opción al final de mi respuesta.

Comment: Si añado cualquier condición en esa query aparece el error del script datatables que indico en la pregunta inicial. Me acabo de dar cuenta que cuando añado tu codigo $query = "SELECT * FROM viajes ORDER BY idviaje DESC limit 0,5"; al final de la tabla apare "Mostrando página 1 de 2 (filtrados de un total de 5 registros)" si no pongo tu filtro solo aparece "Mostrando página 1 de 2" , pero el número de registros que se muestran en pantalla son los mismos.